# Require data in at least one textbox on search page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to require the user to enter data in at least one of five textboxes before running a search query.  .

I'm getting error messages about

1. converting a string to boolean 
   2 "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'"

   ```
   if (txtLoginName.Text=String.Empty && 
       txtDisplayName.Text = String.Empty && 
       txtCode.Text = String.Empty && 
       txtEmailAddress.Text = String.Empty && 
       txtName.Text = String.Empty)
   {

       lblErrorMessage.Text = "At least one search criteria is required.";
       return;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the code below.  In your sample you were using "=" instead of "==" in C#.

```
   if (txtLoginName.Text==String.Empty && 
        txtDisplayName.Text == String.Empty && 
        txtCode.Text == String.Empty && 
        txtEmailAddress.Text == String.Empty && 
        txtName.Text == String.Empty)
```

Another way to accomplish the same thing would be to use this:

```
   if (!String.IsNullorEmpty(txtLoginName.Text) && 
        !String.IsNullorEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text) && 
        !String.IsNullorEmpty(txtCode.Text) && 
        !String.IsNullorEmpty(txtEmailAddress.Text) && 
        !String.IsNullorEmpty(txtName.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to get into the habit of using String.IsNullOrEmpty() instead of a direct comparer.  Although it does the same thing under the hood (AFAIK) it is good discipline for when you are not working with textboxes, but string values that may be null.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLoginName.Text) && 
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text) && 
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCode.Text) && 
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmailAddress.Text) && 
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
{
}
```

</2c>

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses around each test would clarify, too, e.g.

```
if ( (txtLoginName.Text == String.Empty) &&
     (txtDisplayName.Text == String.Empty) )
{
}
```

or

```
if ( (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLoginName.Text)) &&
     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayName.Text)) )
{
}
```

Comment: My personal opinion is that for the String.IsNullOrEmpty version, the extra parentheses clutter things too much.  It is, of course, just my opinion.

Comment: Uh, having had a month to think about it, I agree!